# What the term "devastating milestone" mean literarlly?

Tags: word-meaning

The United Nations Refugee Agency has marked what it calls the "devastating milestone" of registering the one millionth Syrian refugee in Lebanon.

http://www.abc.net.au/news/2014-04-04/united-nations-syria-marks-one-millionth-refugee-lebanon/5367310

My perception is that it is " Very Shocking Event" as oppossed to "Significant event" milestone?? Sad milestone?

Answer (score 1):

It's just terribly sad. The 1,000,000th person isn't any more significant than any of the 999,999 people who came before, it's just a big round number. It makes you realize *just how* big, like a 50th birthday. Milestone is an old term that refers to markers on a highway showing how many miles since the last marker.

The number of 1,000,000 is neither significant nor shocking in and of itself. It's just sad because it causes people to say, "Whoa, how did *this* happen?"

Comment: Mant thanks.  I edited my question to be more clarified. When you say "milestone number" you make "milestone" an adjective, don't you?  Do you mean it is a sad important event during this war ? Does it literally mean that?

Comment: That's the thing, it isn't *really* important. In this context, milestone just emphasizes the big round number, but there isn't really anything significant about the number, except that it is big and round.

Comment: So the *literal* meaning of "milestone" stems from it's archaic use as a highway marker. Yes, it can be used as an adjective, in the OP you use it as a noun. In both cases its use is metaphorical.

Answer (score 0):

Long ago, ancient Romans placed stone pillars called "obelisks" along the sides of roadways. Typically, the stones were placed a mile apart. Each “mile stone" was given a unique number, serving as a mile marker.

Today instead of marking the journey on an actual road, milestones mark significant events.

"Devastating milestone" therefore stands for significant shocking event.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  It is clear the OP knows what a milestone is and asks about the use of the word devastating.